# Using text field in a LIKE function for SOQL query

Tags: soql

I'm trying to query all email messages where the ToAddress contains the case contact email address. I want to know if it's possible to run a query using a text field rather than a string literal when using the LIKE function. For example:

```
SELECT Parent.CaseNumber, Parent.ContactEmail, ToAddress
FROM EmailMessage
WHERE ToAddress LIKE Parent.ContactEmail
```

Comment: Could someone explain why this has been down marked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot reference records' fields in the query. The solution here is to run the for-loop through the all email messages and if `msg.ToAddress == msg.Parent.ContactEmail`, add them to the separate list.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_conditionexpression.htm

As per documentation:

**The value must be a valid value, not other field names or calculations.**

> fieldExpression

> value
> A value used to compare with the value in the fieldName. Supply a value whose data type matches the field type of the specified field. The value must be a valid value, not other field names or calculations. If quotes are required, use single quotes. Double quotes result in an error. Quotes are unnecessary for dates and numbers.

Comment: And use the String class's `contains()` or `startsWith()`, or `endsWith()` instead of doing an equality check if you're looking to emulate the SOQL `LIKE` operator.

Comment: I haven't seen any wildcard symbol in the question, so haven't mentioned it, but you have a point. @DerekF

Comment: @DerekF Using Salesforce Inspector which I believe doesn't allow those classes